# snprintf bug on pebble

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

There seems to be some weirdness with `snprintf` implementation in Pebble Sdk 2.x

I modified the example program to show a click counter. 
The following code works, if I use str[1000] size

```
selectCount ++;
char str[1000], buf[100];
snprintf(str, 1000, "Click %d foo", selectCount);
snprintf(buf, 100,  "s(%d) one two l(%d)", sizeof(str), strlen(str) );

if(selectCount % 2)
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, buf );
else
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, str );
```

But if I reduce the buffer size of str to 400, the application crashes

```
selectCount ++;
char str[400], buf[100];
snprintf(str, 400, "Click %d foo", selectCount);
snprintf(buf, 100,  "s(%d) one two l(%d)", sizeof(str), strlen(str) );

if(selectCount % 2)
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, buf );
else
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, str );
```

But again, if I reduce the size of str to 20, it doesn't crash. Instead it truncates buf at 7 characters; and doesn't display str at all in a text_layer.

The values in the non-crashing cases look okay when I perform

```
APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, str);
```

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calling strlen() on an uninitialized automatic array rarely ends well.

Comment: It that the most simple example that crashes? Can you reproduce without sizeof and strlen. Posting a sscce would be best in this example.

Comment: @MartinJames: But `str` is initialized here, that's not the problem.

Comment: @mafso - you're right, I am wrong:)

Comment: OK then, when you debug it, which line crashes?

Comment: How did you define text_layer?

Comment: @MartinJames It seems that it is crashing during the re-draw cycle, because the function returns without issues.

Comment: @Kalyan02 Did you fix your problem?

Comment: @toasted_flakes I reached out to Pebble Dev support and they have picked it up, as your reasoning makes sense but doesn't quite explain the truncation issue with a second buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a stack buffer, but `text_layer_set_text` doesn't copy its content. When the drawing occurs, the memory doesn't exist anymore.

From the [documentation](http://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/group___text_layer.html#ga19406f772604d595c5c1af7222992449):

> The string is not copied, so its buffer most likely **cannot be stack allocated**, but is recommended to be a buffer that is long-lived, at least as long as the TextLayer is part of a visible Layer hierarchy.

Comment: Correct. Solution is to make the char[] static or make it a global variable.